# Finding best possible combination of 8 elements, one from each of 8 lists

Tags: python, algorithm

My problem is I have 8 lists of size (10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 50) respectively. Each element in each of the lists has a required cost and a value. What I am trying to do is find the combination of 8 elements (1 from each list) that has the highest combined value while not going over the cost cap. What I came up with is as brute force as it gets and as I figured runs out of memory after 1hr before it finishes. Is it worth trying to implement something like an apriori algorithm or is there a better way. What I have so far:

```
import itertools

foo = open("test.txt", "r")

L1 = []
L2 = []
L3 = []
L4 = []
L5 = []
L6 = []
L7 = []
L8 = []

costCap = 10000 #max cost allowed
perfValue = 0 #
final = []

for line in foo:
    line = ','.join(line.split())
    line2 = line.split(",")[1] #values

    if(line2 == "A1"):
        L3.append(line)
    elif(line2 == "A2"):
        L2.append(line)
    elif(line2 == "A3"):
        L5.append(line)
    elif(line2 == "A4"):
        L1.append(line)
    elif(line2 == "A5"):
        L4.append(line)

    L6.append(line)
    L7.append(line)
    L8.append(line)


l1 = list(itertools.product(L1, L2, L5, L4, L3, L6, L7, L8))
for k in range(len(l1)):
    s1 = l1[k][0].split(",")[5]
    s2 = l1[k][1].split(",")[5]
    s3 = l1[k][2].split(",")[5]
    s4 = l1[k][3].split(",")[5]
    s5 = l1[k][4].split(",")[5]
    s6 = l1[k][5].split(",")[5]
    s7 = l1[k][6].split(",")[5]
    s8 = l1[k][7].split(",")[5]
    temp = int(s1[1:]) + int(s2[1:]) + int(s3[1:]) + int(s4[1:]) + int(s5[1:]) + int(s6[1:]) + int(s7[1:]) + int(s8[1:])
    if ((temp > perfValue) and (temp < costCap)):
        perfRating = temp
        final = l1[k]

print(final)
```

Edit1: Sorry alot of that is text file parsing. All that really happens is `l1 = list(itertools.product(L1, L2, L5, L4, L3, L6, L7, L8))` which finds all possible combinations, and then the for loop just checks to see which of the combinations has the highest value while being under the cap.

Comment: of course you runs out of memory, because you first make a list with 12500000000 elements in it, in this case you don't need to make such monstrous list, iterate over the product directly and all the time (and memory) you lost making the list is used in the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory limit you run into is due to how your loop is written it should iterate over the generator of product and not create a list from that generator:

```
for k in itertools.product(L1, L2, L5, L4, L3, L6, L7, L8):
    s1 = k[0].split(",")[5]
    s2 = k[1].split(",")[5]
    s3 = k[2].split(",")[5]
    s4 = k[3].split(",")[5]
    s5 = k[4].split(",")[5]
    s6 = k[5].split(",")[5]
    s7 = k[6].split(",")[5]
    s8 = k[7].split(",")[5]
    temp = int(s1[1:]) + int(s2[1:]) + int(s3[1:]) + int(s4[1:]) + int(s5[1:]) + int(s6[1:]) + int(s7[1:]) + int(s8[1:])
    if ((temp > perfValue) and (temp < costCap)):
        perfRating = temp
        final = k
```

Comment: Would you happen to know what the runtime would look like?

Comment: The time would be at least the product of the lengths of the lists. The product generator can run in constant space. So this code also uses constant space.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve the [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) Take a look, for example [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/20581) for possible approach (a dynamic programming algorithm)

Comment: kk ill look into it.